# how to make shape keys have several drivers, driven by single bone, and then they activate and then turn off when the bone moves to a certain value?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

how to make shape keys have several drivers, driven by single bone, and then they activate and then turn off when the bone moves to a certain value?
[image]
i mean having a driver to activate every shape key at the same time but with a delay in each one, i am using 0.01 as minimum to complete 1.000 to activate the value (using the equation -var x 100 or var x 100 (x is this sign actually *) depending the axis is going whether is positive or negative direction) but using this equation in every shape key in this case "lips-smile" which i made 5 variations, and they get activate together, and they cant be activated together because then this happens:
[image]
so they need to be activated and then turned off to let the other shape key to activate properly, so maybe each one has to multiplied the equation in this case (for example -var x 200, -var x 300 and so on) or do something with the generator modifier in the driver to see if it can get a delay with that instead (or not?), but the thing is that this has to blend as much as possible when the bone is moving in the y axis, so the 5 shapes keys should activate in 0.01 (in increments of 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05) until 0.05 which is the maximum value i added to the limit location constraint to that "lips-smile" bone... so when a shape key passes the 0.01 maximum limit (0.00/0.01 = 1.000) then it should get turn off with the checkbox (or this can be done in the slider instead at the same time adding other variable to the driver?) when it passes that value and then the next one gets activated at the bone current position 0.01 (0.01/0.02= 1.000) until get to 0.02 and so on...

Comment: Assuming absolute shapekeys can't be used here.  Can use a ternary expression in drivers eg `100 * var if (1 < var < 3) else 0`  which when var is 4 is 0 and 200 if var is 2.

Comment: hmm think its not gonna work LOL... where i put that exactly? in the shape key value? well it didnt work, and if you got what i said, is that the 1.000 value triggers another driver, to make the shape key turn off and in the same time make the next shape key to activate the value slider...